# Apartment Year Lease Increase Statement

Tags: united-states, michigan, real-estate-leasing

I'm looking to sign a lease and I notice there is a statement that the landlord can increase rent with 30 days notice. Is this normal for a lease agreement? Should I be concerned?

The exact wording is below:
"Upon thirty (30) days written notice to Resident, Landlord may alter rental payment to cover additional costs in operating the premises
incurred by Landlord because of any increase in ad valorem property taxes, charges for the electricity, heating fuel, and water
consumed at the property, or increases in premiums paid for liability, fire or worker compensation insurance. Any such increased
payment shall be additional rent."

This is in Michigan, just outside the city of Ann Arbor.

Comment: If this is in the US, tax escalator clauses are not uncommon, but I've never seen someone try to tack on insurance/utility increases. In my view that list is too long to be agreeable, if there is more specific language about when these increases can occur that make it clear that they can't arbitrarily jack it up then it might be agreeable.

Comment: If you visit again, mhoran outdid me. He cited your state law, I'd suggest assigning "accepted answer" to him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went to the [state of Michigan for information regarding tenants and landlords](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/documents/publications/tenantlandlord.pdf)

> **Q3    What  provisions  are  prohibited  by  law from  being  included  in  the  lease?**
>
> The  Michigan  Truth  in  Renting  Act  regulates  residential  leases
>   prohibiting  certain  clauses  or  provisions  and  prescribing 
>   penalties. A  provision  or  clause  in  a  lease  that  violates the 
>   Truth  in  Renting  Act  is  void.  In  particular, a  written  lease 
>   shall  not  include a  provision which:
>
> ...
>
> 12. Provides  that  the  landlord  may  alter  a  lease provision  after  the  lease  begins  without  the tenant’s  written  consent,
>       *EXCEPT:  with   30  days’  written  notice,  the  landlord  may make  the  following  types  of  adjustments,  as long  as  there  is  a 
>       clause  in  the  lease allowing  for  the  adjustments:*
>
>     - changes  required  by  federal,  state,  or local  law,  rule,  or  regulation;
>     - changes  in  rules  relating  to  the  property meant  to  protect  health,  safety,  and peaceful  enjoyment;  and
>     - changes  in  the  amount  of  rental  payments to  cover  additional  costs  incurred  by  the landlord  because  of  increases 
>         in  property taxes,  increases  in  utilities,  and  increases  in 
>         property  insurance  premiums.

In other words they can't change the rent unless they give you 30 days notice and it is for one of the stated reasons such as: taxes, utilities, and property insurance. And they have a clause in the lease

Answer (score 6):

Rent laws vary a bit by state, but it sounds like you have a "tenant at will" agreement. It should be both ways, i.e. You can give landlord 30 day notice.

If I am wrong, and you have a year agreement, he's trying to squeeze you on any of his own expenses going up. That means if the 30 days is not reciprocal, you are taking on a huge risk, in my opinion.

Comment: I cannot give my landlord 30 days notice looking later in the contract; this is not reciprocal. Thanks for your info.

Comment: Good point about this being aceptable if month to month, I had assumed in my comment that it was a year-long lease.